# Yocto SRC_URI needs slash '/' but Git repo path has colon ':'

Tags: git, url, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to specify `SRC_URI` in my Yocto recipe but the necessary colon is illegal.
From a shell:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepo.git    # WORKS
git clone git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git    # DOES NOT WORK
```

But Yocto recipe syntax won't accept the `:` and requires that I replace it with `/` and, as with the shell command, it fails.

In my recipe:

```
SRC_URI?= "git://git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/myrepo.git;protocol=git;branch=mybranch"
```

causes the build to fail immediately with a python error to effect of:

```
poky/meta/classes/base.bbclass
  uri = bb.fetch.URI(uri_string)
  self.port = urlp.port
    port = int(port, 10)
    Port could not be cast to integer value as 'mycompany'
```

An this one (with `/` instead of `:`)

```
SRC_URI?= "git://git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git;protocol=git;branch=mybranch"
```

Fails with:

```
ERROR: linux-socfpga-lts-5.4.124-lts+gitAUTOINC+d4d238db6e-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 
'git://git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git;protocol=git;branch=mybranch'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
```

I have also tried the `SRC_URI` definitions without the `git@` part, and also with `protocol=http`. No combination has worked.
How do I get around the incompatible URL syntax between Bitbucket repo and Bitbake?

Comment: Try `ssh://git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git`.

Comment: It didn't like ssh: with protocol=git.  Error msg suggested the reverse so I tried git: with protocol=ssh.  That doesn't do it either.  This is apparently not a common problem; I guess most repo. hosts don't require a colon in the path.

Comment: According the git-fetch manual(https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls), "An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol: [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/"

Comment: Thank you for that pointer.  Seems exactly what I need but... still doesn't work.  I removed the *:// prefix to match the scp syntax and get- "MalformedUrl: The URL: 'git@bitbucket.org:Telestream/linux-socfpga.git;protocol=ssh;branch=tsg-integration-5.4.124;' is invalid and cannot be interpreted"

Comment: ElpieKay, your original answer was spot on.  Not sure what happened yesterday but it worked for me today.  Previously, I must have retained the colon (ssh://... : ...;protocol=git) when it needed to be a slash.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElpieKay had the answer with the appropriate [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls) to explain the options.  This worked for me:

```
SRC_URI = "git://git@bitbucket.org/mycompany/myrepo.git;protocol=ssh;branch=mtbranch;"
```